TV show where characters use books full of gibberish to prove they're dreaming
I have a memory from a few years ago (before 2000, probably before 1995) of a TV show where several characters were in a library; the clothes and setting were similar to how I imagine an Agatha Christie novel to be (but not necessarily British). The characters were debating about whether they were dreaming or not, and one character suggested opening a book in the library and flipping through the pages; if it were really a dream, their subconscious would not be able to create a plausible story or even logical sentences, and it would prove that they're dreaming.
Anyone have any ideas on what show this might be?

no, but it happened once in an episode of the Batman animated series.

There's an episode of Futurama which is vaguely similar (the one where big brains take over the planet).

It was the Batman episode. I'll accept it if you post it as an answer. The rest was a false memory. I watched that show religiously right around the time I have this memory from.

I have no real idea what the actual TV show you're thinking of is, but TV tropes does have a page on the general concept: Blank Book. The page describes this as "Type 1":

Type 1: It may be that the character is trapped in a Lotus-Eater Machine of some kind and the book being empty or filled with nonsense is a sign that something isn't right, since a Master of Illusion would have to manually "write" each and every book himself. 

However, the TV show section of the page is woefully short, and none of the few "Live Action TV" examples seem to fit your description. (Of course, you didn't necessarily specify that it wasn't a cartoon, but I figured you would have mentioned it if it was.)

This really doesn't answer the question being asked. You merely provided a link to a larger description of the concept the poster is using to frame their question, but your post doesn't answer what they're asking, which is, "What show is this?"

You're thinking of Perchance to Dream, an episode from the Batman Animated Series.
IMDB
Batters gets knocked on the noggin and is put into a dreamworld by

 the Mad Hatter

Lots of things are different than he remembers, but everything seems so real.  His suspicions are confirmed:

Further evidence that something is very wrong comes when Bruce attempts to read first a newspaper and then a book from his personal library, discovering that the text is a garbled and unreadable mess.

Eventually he breaks out of the dream and everything is good for the next episode.

This brings to mind Inception, although the timeframe isnt right... It does feature a scene early on where pages on documents are seen to be blank within a dream, and the film is based on the idea of dreams and trying to work out whether a character is dreaming or awake.
